# How do I pass an Array vlaue out of a function using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, global, local

I am an absolute JavaScript newbie, however I am working on a private Project.  In a nutshell I will be reading a few flat files (.csv/.txt format) and passing the values to HighCharts.

I have a handle on nearly everything (I think).

The only bit I can't get is reading the files into an array, then picking the bits out I need.  I can use a script to pass the files straight into Highcharts, but it's not flexible enough for what I need.

Anyway for the below Livedata.txt contains

**1370576580,Acidity,pH,8.20,ORP,mV,366.99,ReefTemp,DegC,25.1,RoomTemp,DegC,21.7,HeaterTemp,DegC,25.1**

(EPOCH, then groups of 3 data points (measure, unit, value) for 5 probes)

My (the snippet of my) script is:

---

```
var $livedata = new Array();
var currentph;
$.get('livedata.txt', function(data){
        livedata = data.split(',');
});
currentph = $livedata[3];
document.write("<b>currentph is </b>=>"+currentph+"<br>");
```

---

like this the var currentph = undefined

If I move the document.write statement into the $.get (is this a function?) it does contain the value 8.20

Furthermore if I declare currentph as 8.20 the rest of my script accepts this value fine.

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

I will be declaring 16 variables, 1 for each value in the array (just for the sake of reading the script later).

Cheers

Comment: Did you remember to include your jQuery library in order to be able to use [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)?

Comment: Looks like you're using jquery because the $.get() function/method is from jquery library see here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Sorry - yes.  All the JavaScript does work, I just can't get the livedata array (read inside the $get function) to pass it's values out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `$.get` is asyn. When you call `currentph = $livedata[3];` right after that, the response does not arrive yet. That's the reason why it works when you move  the `document.write` statement into the `$.get`'s callback function. Also check your typo, you're missing `$` before `livedata`. If you need to do syn call, you can try `$.ajax` with `async:false`

```
$.ajax(
     {
       url:'livedata.txt', 
       async:false,
       success: function(data){
         $livedata = data.split(',');
       }
    }
);
```

Comment: Is there any way to force a wait until it has passed the array back?  Some of the other files I plan on reading will contain much more data.

Comment: you can use $.ajax with setting async:false

Comment: Thanks @Khanh TO - will check it out.  What library do I need to reference to use ajax (sorry for the newbie question)

Comment: would this line cover it -        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

Comment: yes, $.ajax and $.get come from the same jquery library @user2462057

Comment: will do - however now nothing is coming up.  I will keep trying and make sure my browser is not affecting it and come back with an answer (and rate as correct if it works).  Thanks

Comment: I have others issues now, but your code fixed my issue (you just need another } to close the success function).  Many Thanks

Comment: @user2462057: that was a small typo. Edited. Sorry that It caused you problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to prefix `$` to your variable `livedata`.
2. Other issues with your code are that; a) If 'livedata.txt' is never loaded, `$livedata` would be an empty array; b) If 'livedata.txt' is loaded, but does not have at least 4 comma separated values, the `$livedata[3]` would be undefined.

You may want to re-write your code with something like this:

```
var $livedata = []; // array literal notation

$.get('livedata.txt', function(data){
        $livedata = data.split(',');
});

// in case array does not have an index 3, set value to 'not found'
var currentph = $livedata[3] || 'not found';

document.write("<b>currentph is </b>=>"+currentph+"<br>");
```